# Jcombobox dentro de um JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

Bom dia,
Tenho uma lista de alguns motivos

```
 private List<Motivo> motivos;
```

E preciso preencher um jComboBox com essa lista e conseguir obter a opção selecionada.

Atualmente eu fiz com MessageDialog onde eu consigo preencher normalmente porém não consigo obter o item selecionado, segue exemplo:

```
 JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox();
    for (Motivo motivos_bloqueia : motivos) {
        jcb.addItem(motivos_bloqueia.getMotivo());

    }

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jcb, "Selecione o motivo", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

Porém desta forma não consigo obter o item selecionado.

Li em alguns fóruns onde era orientado a usar um InputDialog ao inves do MessageDialog, da seguinte forma:

```
Object[] opcoes = {"Um","Dois","Tres","Quatro"};
Object res = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Escolha um item" , "Selecao
de itens" ,
JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE , null ,opcoes,"");
```

Dessa forma eu teria o item selecionado na variavel 'res'. O problema é que o parâmetro que ele passa para o combobox adicionar os itens nas opções é um   Object[] e no caso o que eu tenho é uma List.

De que forma consigo obter o item que o usuário selecionou no combobox ao clicar em OK?

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora @diegofm

Comment: Fiz um exemplo idêntico ao seu e não houve nenhum problema. Seja mais especifico onde está ocorrendo o problema, o código informado não tem nada de errado.

Comment: Ficou meio confusa a pergunta, tentei editar não sei se ajudou.
Sendo mais direto ao ponto, preciso OBTER o item selecionado pelo usuário no jComboBox ao ele clicar em OK no meu JOptionPane.

Apenas consegui fazer isso usando showInputDialog passando os itens para o combo box como Object[], porém eu tenho uma List<Motivos> e não consigo usar o InputDialog com ela.

Comment: Essa abordagem não é muito boa, o JOptionPane foi feito para tarefas mais simples, isso que você está tentando fazer, seria o caso de usar uma tela com JFrame e adicionar os componentes corretos nela. O retorno do JOptionPane é para coisas menos complexas e simples, onde construir uma tela causaria mais trabalho do que usar este componente.

Comment: Imagina se cada coisa que você precisar obter do usuario fazer um JOptionPane? Sua aplicação vai ficar extremamente cansativa de manusear. AS vezes é melhor fazer uma telinha e colocar tudo ali pro usuario fazer tudo q tiver que fazer e depois você só tratar as entradas dele de uma só vez.

Comment: Realmente é uma abordagem digamos meio 'estranha'. Quis evitar de criar uma nova 'telinha' e fazer com o JOptionPane pois somente teria um jCombobox dentro, digamos que não seja o método correto de ser feito hehehe, irei substituir. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um `JOptionPane` não retorna o conteúdo de um componente inserido nele, como um combobox, pois cada componente já possui todos os métodos necessários para que seu conteúdo possa ser manipulado. No caso do `JComboBox`, creio que esteja havendo um equivoco, você não vai obter o item selecionado pelo `JOptionPane`, é preciso chamar [**`getSelectedItem()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem()) do próprio componente para obter isso. Veja um exemplo abaixo, usando seu código:

```
JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    jcb.addItem("motivo 0" + (i + 1));
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jcb, "Selecione o motivo", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jcb.getSelectedItem(), "Opção selecionada", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Entendi, consegui resolver com sua explicação.

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta não está muito clara. Parece que desejas que aconteça alguma coisa ao se clicar no botão. Nesse caso, use `OptionDialog`, que retorna um `int` e, a partir do valor retornado, fazer algo.

```
    JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox();
        for (Motivo motivos_bloqueia : motivos) {
            jcb.addItem(motivos_bloqueia.getMotivo());

        }

    int selecionado = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, jcb, "Selecione o motivo", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if (selecionado == 1) {
        //faça algo
    }
```

Vale notar que podes usar ENUM se sua lista de motivos for previamente conhecida. Bastará atribuir a cada valor do ENUM um equivalente `int`.

Comment: Ele quer pegar o item selecionado no combo, não o retorno do jOptionpane.